# Using jquery, how can I select dynamically created text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I already know to use on("click") for situations that involve applying click events to dynamically created objects. In this case, I want to click on a button to select the text of another object.

```
  <div class="main">
     <div class="temp"><p></p></div>
     <button class="degrees">Celsius</button>
  </div>
```

Here's a sample of my HTML. Basically, when the page loads, data is dynamically added to the empty paragraph. I want to be able to select the text in the paragraph, and perform operations on it. The text of the paragraph will display the temperature, and I want to have a function that toggles Celsius and Fahrenheit.

You can see the site in action over at http://codepen.io/Matiny/full/NjKEqw/

Comment: So what did you try?

Comment: I tried using on(click) only to realize that it only works if you are clicking on the dynamically added element, which is not the case here.

Comment: Not clear what you mean, by it only works by *"clicking on the dynamically added element"*.... Isn't that what you are clicking? You click on the button, reference the sibling, get the text, run the function to convert it, put the text back, swap the button text"

Comment: Can't you just give the p tag an id? Then just use jQuery to target the text inside it?

Comment: @Matiny: The title of your question implies there is a *dynamically created text*. Please post the code for that dynamic text creation and you will hopefully get more help

Comment: @epascarello The idea is to have the user click the button with the degrees class, which selects the dynamically loaded text inside the paragraph and can swap between celsius and fahrenheit.

Comment: so select the sibling to the button, read the text. https://api.jquery.com/prev/

Comment: @jrook I put it all over on Codepen. Take a look.

Comment: Does my solution not work??

Comment: I'll try it out, as I was just throwing everything online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit you can use this formula:

`T(°F) = T(°C) × 1.8 + 32`

and to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius you can use this formula:

`T(°C) = (T(°F) - 32) / 1.8`

this code is tested and work on your codepen

```
$('.degrees').on('click', function() {
    var currentDegree = parseInt($('.temp').text());
    if($(this).text() == 'Celsius') {
        var fahrenheit = currentDegree * 1.8 + 32;
        $('.temp').text(fahrenheit);
        $(this).text('Fahrenheit');
    } else {
        var celsius = (currentDegree - 32) / 1.8;
        $('.temp').text(celsius);
        $(this).text('Celsius');
    }
});
```

Comment: I ended up finding the answer on my own. Sorry for wasting you guys' time.

Answer (score 0):

```
JQuery(document).on ("click", ".degrees", function  () {

    JQuery(".temp").html("30");

}
```

This should change that HTML of the div tag with class .temp to read "30" anytime you click the button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
 $('.degrees').click(function(){
 
  var range = document.createRange();
    var selection = window.getSelection();
 
     range.selectNodeContents(document.getElementById('select-text'));   
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
 
 
 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
     <div class="temp"><p id="select-text">Your dymic loaded data</p></div>
     <button class="degrees">Celsius</button>
  </div>
```